# Selected value of selectlist is not set in @html.dropdownlistfor() in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

controller action:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult EditProject(int? id)
 {
    var project = _projectService.GetProjectById(id);
    var selectedEngagementManager =     _projectService.GetEmployeeById(project.EngagementManagerId);

   var selectedProjectManager = _projectService.GetEmployeeById(project.ProjectManagerId);

 ViewBag.EngageMentManagers = new SelectList(_projectService.GetAllEmployee(), "EmployeeId", "EmployeeId", selectedEngagementManager.EmployeeId); 

 ViewBag.ProjectManagers = new SelectList(_projectService.GetAllEmployee(), "EmployeeId", "EmployeeId", selectedProjectManager.EmployeeId);

return View(project);
}
```

**view**

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Project Manager", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProjectManagerId, (SelectList)ViewBag.ProjectManagers, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProjectManagerId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AdditionalNotes, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AdditionalNotes, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AdditionalNotes, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

here selected value is not going to displayed in dropdownlist in view..it just sselect  last value in dropdownlist always

Comment: Put a breakpoint and see what value you have in `selectedEngagementManager.EmployeeId`, which you are passing to the SelectList class'es constructor's last param.

Comment: selectedEngagementManager.EmployeeId contains correct value..If we put @Html.dropdownList() instead of @html.DropDownListFor() then it shows selected value

Comment: Got a solution..I just changed the viewbag name ..and it is reflecting the selected value in view..i think there was conflict in model property name and viewbag name but not sure this was the only reasin..thanks to all for contributing

Comment: There is no conflict. Delete the last parameter of your `SelectList` constructor i.e. `selectedProjectManager.EmployeeId` because its ignored by the `DropDownListFor()` method when you bind to a property. Its the value of property that determines which option is selected - thats how model binding works. You need to set the value of `ProjectManagerId` in the controller and if its value matches one of the options, it will be selected.